# How should "Aurora's Vow" be translated into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, genitive, gender, agreement

I haven't taken Latin in a few years, so forgive me for any simple mistakes.

I'm trying to translate "Aurora's Vow" from English to Latin for the title of a song I'm writing. My question is how it would be translated (since *Aurora* is in the first declension and *Votum* is in the second. It seems to me that the answer would be *Votum Aurorae*, but would there be a discrepancy between the genders (neuter and feminine)?

(There's also the issue that the above doesn't sound very poetic, so a better translation would also be welcome.)

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 6):

I actually think you are spot on! For this usage of the genitive, there is little need to match the genders of the nouns. Both *Aurora* and *votum* are their own, separate entities, so they do not need to match. *Votum Aurorae* is therefore a good translation.

Now, I can't really make too much of a comment on how poetic it is. I, personally, think it is fine. But to change it up, you could go a couple of directions. Aurora was the goddess of the dawn, so one could try to find other options that mean "dawn," "sunrise," etc. You could also try to find adjectives that mean "of the dawn," in which case you would need to match the gender to *votum*. One could also find other substitutes for *votum*. Below are some options I found. It is really up to you to determine what is most poetic.

Nouns = "Dawn," "Sunrise"

- *ortus, ortus*, m.
- *Eosos, Eosi*, f.
- *oriens, orientis*, m.

Adjectives = "of the dawn," "of the sunrise,"

- *antelucanus, antelucana, antelucanum*

Nouns = "vow," "promise"

- *debitum, debiti*, n.
- *convotus, convoti*, m.
- *promissio, promissionis*, f.
- *promissum, promissi*, n.
- *pollicitatio, pollicitationis*, f.
- *pollicitum, polliciti*, n.
- *stipulatio, stipulationis*, f.
- *credentia, credentiae*, f.

Comment: My Latin is rusty, but it's equally valid to say *"Aurorae Votum"*, right? The OP may find that more poetic.

Comment: @fredsbend Yes, that is also perfectly grammatical